# Two animations at the same time on the same view in UIView

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

I have one `UIImageView` and I want to apply **two different animations** to it, and run them at the same time. The first animation set the **opacity** from 0 to 1, the second animation **moves** the UIView from one point to another. And when the UIView did load, the two animations start together.

Is that possibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CGPoint movePoint = Your end animation point;
yourView.opaque = 0.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
        animations:^{ 
            yourView.center = movePoint;
           yourview.opaque = 1.0

        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){

           //Animation completed

        }];
```

Comment: Awesome! That method works only for UIViews or "yourView" object could be even a UIImageView?

Comment: its a generic code, i mean "yourView" may be class of UIImageview or UIView yeah some other controls those are inherit from UIView class.

Comment: @Wildchild89 you would still write `[UIView animateWith...]` but you can animate image views inside the block

Comment: @iHungry Thank god you changed the `center` and not the `frame` in order to move the view. That is a huge pet peeve of mine :D

Comment: also you can handle multiple animations for multipleview at same time and also you can create nested animation one after one.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, it doesn't matter your move your view using frame or using center point, its completely depends on your requirement and thining.

Comment: @iHungry You are mostly correct. If transforms are involved then the frame will give you strange (read undefined) results but the center will work fine. However my real point is that changing the center speaks the intent of the animation much clearer than changing the frame.

Comment: Yes. In my point of just view moving animation using center is more affordable than frame. Because While animation of frame iOS check origin and size both that means 4 parameter but in case of of center it just check 2 parameter from CGPoint.